# Can $\sin(x^2)$ be solution of the diff equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$ in some interval containing $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous functions for any $x$, can $y(x)=\sin(x^2)$ be solution of the diff equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$  in some interval $I=[a,b] $containing $0$? I think it is not as simple as replacing $\sin(x^2)$ into the equation and analyzing the obtained expression.

Answer (score 2):

We have $y = \sin (x^2)$, $y' = 2x \cos (x^2)$, and $y'' = 2 \cos(x^2) - 4x^2 \sin (x^2)$. Substituting,

$$ 2 \cos(x^2) - 4x^2 \sin (x^2) + p(x) 2x \cos (x^2) + q(x) \sin (x^2) = 0$$

Following A.G.'s solution given in the comments, setting $x=0$ in the equation gives $2=0$ if we assume $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ being bounded in a neighbourhood of $0$. Hence $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: How do you infer that "we must have $p(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ and $q(x) = 4x^2$" ?

Comment: The solution must satisfy the differential equation, so the LHS must be zero.

Comment: Basically you're saying that $\forall x, (f(x)\cos(x^2)+ g(x)\sin(x^2) = 0 )\implies f=0 \;\text{and}\; g=0$. That doesn't seem trivial, or even true.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM You're correct. Let me think about it some more. For now I will leave this solution up until somebody else makes an attempt.

Comment: Setting $x=0$ in the equation gives $2=0$ if we assume $p,q$ being bounded in a neighbourhood of zero. Hence $p,q$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: @A.G. Thank you, I have updated my answer :).

Answer (score 0):

One can also use the standard argument about existence and uniqueness of Cauchy problem like [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). By this theorem, a linear differential equation with continuous coefficients has a *unique* solution with given initial condition at a point (see, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1361997/does-the-cauchy-lipschitz-theorem-extend-to-higher-order-des)). Assuming $y(x)=\sin(x^2)$ to be a solution, it solves the Cauchy problem with $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ together with the trivial solution $y=0$. It contradicts the uniqueness.